# POST http://localhost/DemoWebsite/wp-admin/custom_Settings.php 404 (Not Found) after ajax call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, url

My server giving me the response as following 
 
when my ajax call to the same page. Before Ajax call everything is working fine on console but after ajax call and updating database, this error is occurring. I think my Ajax_url is not correct but I want to get ajax data on same page that name is "custom_Settings.php" as mentioned in url.
Please help me to solve this error.
Thanks!

> jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST
>   http://localhost/DemoWebsite/wp-admin/custom_Settings.php 404 (Not
>   Found)

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
saveNewPositions();
});
function saveNewPositions(){
        var positions = [];
        $j('.updated').each(function(){
            positions.push([$j(this).attr('data-index'), $j(this).attr('data-position')]);
            $j(this).removeClass('updated');
        });
        $j.ajax({
           url: 'custom_Settings.php',
           method: 'POST',
           dataType: 'text',
           data: {
            update: 1,
            positions: positions
           }, success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
           }
        });
    }  
  </script>
```

**PHP**

```
function wp_pageOrdering_field_settings(){
      global $wpdb;
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        foreach($_POST['positions'] as $position){
            $index = $position[0];
            $newPosition = $position[1];
        }
        $wpdb->update(
           'wp_page_settings',
           array('page_order' => $newPosition),
           array('ID' => $index)
        );
        wp_die();
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                  <table class="table table-stripped table-hover table-border">
                      <head>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Page Title</td>
                          </tr>

                      </head>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php 

    $var = get_option('Accessable_Pages');
    $list = implode(",", $var);
    $newRes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, page_order FROM wp_page_settings WHERE ID IN ($list) ORDER BY page_order ASC",ARRAY_A); 
        if($newRes){
        foreach ($newRes as $value1 ) {
            echo '
               <tr data-index="'.$value1['ID'].'" data-position="'.$value1['page_order'].'">
                   <td>'.$value1['post_title'].'</td>
               </tr>
            ';
        }
        }
        ?>

                      </tbody>
                  </table>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```